# Powershell Need to pass multiple values to variables in Powershell via Read-Host

Tags: powershell

Before we get going, YES, we MUST use Read-Host.

I'm creating a script to "do something"

but first the end user has to input the values necessary (dept#). If it were always a set number of values, this would be easy. But it's not always a set number of values

```
$response = Read-Host 'Enter the department you want to index (e.g., dept00) or press N'
if ($response -ne 'n') {
<do things based on user input>
}
until ($response -eq 'N')
```

The catch is that it might be dept00, dept05, dept16 today but tomorrow it might be 20 different departments. **This must be entered manually by the end user.**

Each  can take about 5 min to run, so I'd prefer if all of the 'depts' could be entered first then it all runs after the user enters the dept numbers.

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Whats your programming question?

Comment: How to pass multiple values to a variable using Read-Host

Comment: You can tell the users to input them comma separated then split by commas. Obviously not robust.

Comment: I considered that but need something more bulletproof. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `Read-Host` then :) You can use regex to see if any value inputted by users don't match `deptXXXX` where `X` represent a numeric digit. Still, not super robust.

Comment: gotta use read-host, see opening statement.

Comment: Or, is there a way to make it create a new variable until user presses N.. e.g,  $var1, $var2, $var3.. etc.

Comment: You can do it with a simple `Do{}Until()`, you just need to define your `$response` as an array first, and use `+=` in the `Do` loop. Something like `$response=@();Do{$response += Read-Host 'Enter the department you want to index (e.g., dept00) or press N'}until($response -match '^n$')` Then you can loop through departments, or create jobs to run them in parallel, or whatever you want to do.

Comment: The terms "bulletproof" and "manual user input" seldom go together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really, as you have stated in comments, a *"bulletproof"* way to handle this but you can get closer to something robust using a regex pattern to check if the inputted value **starts with the word `dept` followed by 2 numeric digits (`[0-9]{2}`)**. You can, in addition, use a [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-8.0) to get unique values. Then this process can be repeated using a [`while` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_while?view=powershell-7.4) until the user input **is equal to `N`**.

```bash
function Read-Department {
    $departments = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
        [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

    while ($true) {
        $response = (Read-Host 'Enter the department you want to index (e.g., dept00) or press N').Trim()
        if ($response -eq 'N') {
            return $departments
        }

        if ($response -notmatch '^dept[0-9]{2}$') {
            Write-Warning "Inputted value '$response' does not meet criteria."
            continue
        }

        if (-not $departments.Add($response)) {
            Write-Warning "Inputted value '$response' is duplicated, skipping."
        }
    }
}

$departmentsToProcess = Read-Department
$departmentsToProcess
```